# Random Number from range

Tags: array, range

What is the best way to get a random number within a certain range?

I made something but I guess there is a better way:

In this example I want to position some elements randomly. This approach works, but I have to define a variable for each value.

```
{% set randomizr = range(10, 90) %}

{% set randomHeight1 = shuffle(randomizr) | first %}
{% set randomWidth1 = shuffle(randomizr) | first %}

{% set randomHeight2 = shuffle(randomizr) | first %}
{% set randomWidth2 = shuffle(randomizr) | first %}

{% set randomHeight3 = shuffle(randomizr) | first %}
{% set randomWidth3 = shuffle(randomizr) | first %}

{% set randomHeight4 = shuffle(randomizr) | first %}
{% set randomWidth4 = shuffle(randomizr) | first %}

{% set randomHeight5 = shuffle(randomizr) | first %}
{% set randomWidth5 = shuffle(randomizr) | first %}

<div class="sandbox">
    <div style="left: {{ randomHeight1 }}%; top: {{ randomWidth1 }}%;"></div>
    <div style="left: {{ randomHeight2 }}%; top: {{ randomWidth2 }}%;"></div>
    <div style="left: {{ randomHeight3 }}%; top: {{ randomWidth3 }}%;"></div>
    <div style="left: {{ randomHeight4 }}%; top: {{ randomWidth4 }}%;"></div>
    <div style="left: {{ randomHeight5 }}%; top: {{ randomWidth5 }}%;"></div>
</div>
```

Is this somehow possible without writing each variable manually?

Comment: I don't know what you're creating, but does it make sense to explore changing these values in JavaScript rather than directly in the markup?

Comment: Yeah I taught about that too but first I'd like to see if it's possible within twig.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Building off of Brad's answer, you might consider using a `for` loop to render your markup, instead of setting all of those variables:

```
{% set range = range(10, 90) %}
{% set totalDivs = 5 %}

<div class="sandbox">
  {% for i in 1..totalDivs %}
    <div style="left: {{ random(range) }}%; top: {{ random(range) }}%;"></div>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using [shuffle](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/extensions/array.html), which is only available in the extra [Array extensions library](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/extensions/index.html#extensions-install), you could just use [random](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/extensions/index.html#extensions-install).

```
{% set range = range(10, 90) %}

{% set randomHeight1 = random(range) %}
{% set randomWidth1 = random(range) %}

{% set randomHeight2 = random(range) %}
{% set randomWidth2 = random(range) %}

...
```

Comment: There is this crazy cool CMS named Craft, that adds some Twig functions on top of the default ones and [`shuffle`](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/functions#shuffle) is one of them! ;-)

Comment: I'll have to check it out sometime! :)